# How to change g_initialized in ros::init

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm developing a QT interface to manage two or more robots, each having its own ros master (this is mandatory).
My QT interface consists of a qtalker, and I'd like to switch it runtime from a robot to another (i.e. from a ros master to another).
To do so, I shutdown the current qtalker node, and then I restart it (runtime) calling again ros::init after passing it new master IP/port in remappings.
The problem I find is that new parameters are not received, so that old master is again linked to qtalker.

I found, in init.cpp, the static variable "g_initialized", which is set to "true" the first time ros::init is called, and than doesn't allow new remappings are read the second time ros::init is called.
I think this is the reason for which the new master cannot be linked.

Two questions:

1. Am I right?
2. There is any workaround?

Thanks very much

Paolo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220436/how-to-change-g_initialized-in-ros::init/) by [VenusRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/24997/venusrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-11-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I know switching the master context in code is not supported, although it would be nice.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VenusRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/24997/venusrobot/) on 2015-11-05**:
You're probably right, I'm quite new in Ros.
Nevertheless it would be interesting to know if it would be possible to edit init.cpp (in order to modify g_initialized behaviour) or if it is strictly forbidden (e. g. due to known/unknown side effects).

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-11-05**:
My feeling would be that that is not safe, because otherwise the feature might have been exposed. However, that is something to be answered by the ROS developers.

**Comment by [VenusRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/24997/venusrobot/) on 2015-11-05**:
I agree with you, I look forward to a ROS developers answer.
Thank you